# Are X509Certificates enums like StoreName and StoreLocation sufficient for both Windows and Macos platforms?

Tags: .net, windows, macos, asp.net-core-2.0, x509certificate

I am new to .Net and X509Certificates. I am to write an application using .net core to find all the installed certificates for both Windows and Mac.
I have gone through this example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.location?view=netframework-4.7.2). I was wondering if

1. These enums work for both Windows and Macos?
2. Should that be sufficient on both the platforms to find all the installed certificates?

Thanks.

Comment: The classes were designed for Windows, and Microsoft maps them to the corresponding Mac locations, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20324 It would be too broad to say "sufficient" or not. What's your exact scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enums "work" in that you can pass them in.  But on macOS only the following StoreName values will succeed:

- My (read-write, delete will fail if any custom trust rules were applied)
- Root (read-only)
- Disallowed (read-only)

`My` corresponds to either `System.keychain` (`LocalMachine`) or `login.keychain` (`CurrentUser`).

> 2. Should that be sufficient on both the platforms to find all the installed certificates?

No, they're not sufficient on any platform to find *all* installed certificates.

- On macOS any number of keychains can be created, and .NET has no way of enumerating them.
- On Windows any number of custom-named stores can be created, and .NET has no way of enumerating them.
- On both systems things could be installed under different users.

But enumerating the `My` store for "usable certificates" or the `Root` store for "trusted certificates" is a sufficient 99% solution on both platforms.